# svn track brand new code base

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm at a company, we keep recieviing new codebases from a third party vendor.

we'd like to track the changes in subversion. is there a way to replace a branch with the new code and track the changes?

currently we just delete all files in the branch, and then add the new files and commit.

we'd like to track the files, but I havn't found a tool that will easily deal with all the .svn directories found in subfolders.

does anyone know a tool that will replace an svn directory with a new branch and create the respective modify add and delete records as if the code base was organically modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete your files but not the _svn or .svn folders. Then just drop their files in the working copy , keeping your _svn folders This way svn will be able to track the revisions

Comment: sweet! I'll have to write a bash script to automate it, I think there are around 37 top level directories to the project (third party vendors, I know)

Comment: This won't deal with the problem of file deletions/additions, but I think the SVN folks have a script for that.

Comment: @sbi. file deletions will be marked as missingg and can be catered for when comitting

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

Answer (score 1):

Go through their code drop, and delete all of the .svn directories and the contents of those directories.  I'm surprised they sent them to you anyway.  If you copy whats left into your existing directory structure (with your .svn directories intact) and then commit, you should get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

svn_load_dirs.pl (in the book) is what we used to bring in vendor branch. Worked quite well.